# LVM2 Raid 1 "needs refresh", but does not refresh or scrub

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, lvm, lvm2

I'm running a LVM RAID 1 on two disks. Here is what `lvs` tells my about my VG:

```
root@picard:~# lvs -a -o +devices,lv_health_status,raid_sync_action,raid_mismatch_count 
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  LV                 VG      Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices                                 Health          SyncAction Mismatches
  lv-data            vg-data rwi-aor-r- 2.70t                                    100.00           lv-data_rimage_0(0),lv-data_rimage_1(0) refresh needed  idle                0
  [lv-data_rimage_0] vg-data iwi-aor-r- 2.70t                                                     /dev/sda(0)                             refresh needed                       
  [lv-data_rimage_1] vg-data iwi-aor--- 2.70t                                                     /dev/sdb(1)                                                                  
  [lv-data_rmeta_0]  vg-data ewi-aor-r- 4.00m                                                     /dev/sda(708235)                        refresh needed                       
  [lv-data_rmeta_1]  vg-data ewi-aor--- 4.00m                                                     /dev/sdb(0)
```

It looks like something went wrong on `/dev/sda`. The SMART-log of that disk looks good, so I hope it's just something temporary, and I would like to refresh / resync my RAID. Here's what I do:

```
root@picard:~# lvchange --refresh vg-data/lv-data
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.

(…wait for a couple of minutes…)

root@picard:~# lvs -a -o +devices,lv_health_status,raid_sync_action,raid_mismatch_count
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  LV                 VG      Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices                                 Health          SyncAction Mismatches
  lv-data            vg-data rwi-aor-r- 2.70t                                    100.00           lv-data_rimage_0(0),lv-data_rimage_1(0) refresh needed  idle                0
  [lv-data_rimage_0] vg-data iwi-aor-r- 2.70t                                                     /dev/sda(0)                             refresh needed                       
  [lv-data_rimage_1] vg-data iwi-aor--- 2.70t                                                     /dev/sdb(1)                                                                  
  [lv-data_rmeta_0]  vg-data ewi-aor-r- 4.00m                                                     /dev/sda(708235)                        refresh needed                       
  [lv-data_rmeta_1]  vg-data ewi-aor--- 4.00m                                                     /dev/sdb(0)
```

So, that didn't do anything? My dmesg indicates that it tried to recover the RAID:

```
[150522.459416] device-mapper: raid: Faulty raid1 device #0 has readable super block.  Attempting to revive it.
```

Well, okay, maybe scrubbing helps? Let's try that:

```
root@picard:~# lvchange --syncaction repair vg-data/lv-data
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
root@picard:~# lvs -a -o +devices,lv_health_status,raid_sync_action,raid_mismatch_count
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  LV                 VG      Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices                                 Health          SyncAction Mismatches
  lv-data            vg-data rwi-aor-r- 2.70t                                    100.00           lv-data_rimage_0(0),lv-data_rimage_1(0) refresh needed  idle                0
  [lv-data_rimage_0] vg-data iwi-aor-r- 2.70t                                                     /dev/sda(0)                             refresh needed                       
  [lv-data_rimage_1] vg-data iwi-aor--- 2.70t                                                     /dev/sdb(1)                                                                  
  [lv-data_rmeta_0]  vg-data ewi-aor-r- 4.00m                                                     /dev/sda(708235)                        refresh needed                       
  [lv-data_rmeta_1]  vg-data ewi-aor--- 4.00m                                                     /dev/sdb(0)
```

Here, there are several things weird:

- The `SyncAction` is `idle`, i.e., it looks like scrubbing finished instantly?
- If scrubbing is finished, *and* the array still needs a refresh, how can the mismatch count still be 0? Shouldn't scrubbing detect mismatches and either correct them (i.e., clear the "refresh needed" status) or raise the mismatch count to non-zero?

dmesg says:

```
[150695.091180] md: requested-resync of RAID array mdX
[150695.092285] md: mdX: requested-resync done.
```

That also looks like the scrubbing didn't really do anything.

## Questions

- How do I invoke actual scrubbing?
- Assuming that the drive isn't faulty - how do I refresh the array?
- If the drive was faulty (i.e., refreshing ran into an error immediately) - how would I see that? I'm assuming dmesg should show some I/O errors? (I don't see any of them…)

## System Information

I'm running Armbian based on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. LVM version:

```
root@picard:~# lvm version
  LVM version:     2.02.133(2) (2015-10-30)
  Library version: 1.02.110 (2015-10-30)
  Driver version:  4.37.0
```